# How can I bring the modification of a list from the values ​of a set to java stream?

Tags: java, set, java-stream

I am currently working with Java and practicing my programming logic and as a good practice I am trying to apply stream in some operations with Java collections.

In this case I have a method that receives a string and a set list, the string must be taken to a list to replace its characters according to the values ​​found in the Set, once replaced they are taken back to string and It is returned:

```
private static String wordToGuess(String word,List<Integer> valueUniqueToRemplace){
    List<String> wordToList=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(word.split("")));
    for (Integer integer : valueUniqueToRemplace) {
        wordToList.set(integer, "_");
    }
    return wordToList.stream().map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining(""));
}
```

How could I replace the for loop and what is done within it with a stream function?

Comment: Why would you want to? Streams are best suited for operations that don’t modify anything outside the stream pipeline. I would unconditionally prefer to keep the `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks for the information!!..As a curiosity, when is it advisable to apply stream?

Comment: Hard to say in general. I often use a stream pipeline exactly where it does not produce any other effect than the return value from its terminal operation. And I always think twice, try the stream approach, evaluate it, and if I am not sure, also try a loop approach and see which I like better.

Comment: You already got a good answer but even when keeping your approach, you should notice that some things are entirely obsolete: 1) copying the list into an `ArrayList`; you can simply use `List<String> wordToList=Arrays.asList(word.split(""));` 2) the `.map(String::valueOf)`; the elements are already strings. You can use `return wordToList.stream() .collect(Collectors.joining(""));` or even `return String.join("", wordToList);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> as a good practice I am trying to apply stream in some operations with Java collections

Practice is good but also notice when it makes sense to use a certain language construct and when not. Not every task is suitable to be solved with streams. If I see it correctly, you are trying to replace certain indices of a string with underscores. This is not clear, at least at first glance at your method. I would have written something like below, which is easier to understand:

```
private static String wordToGuess1(String word,List<Integer> valueUniqueToReplace){
    char[] chars = word.toCharArray();
    valueUniqueToReplace.forEach(i -> chars[i] = '_');
    return String.valueOf(chars);
}
```

or

```
private static String wordToGuess2(String word,List<Integer> valueUniqueToReplace){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(word);
    valueUniqueToReplace.forEach(i -> sb.setCharAt(i, '_'));
    return sb.toString();
}
```

There are certainly better approaches but spontaneously I think of the following alternatives with streams:

```
private static String wordToGuess3(String word,List<Integer> valueUniqueToReplace){
    return IntStream.range(0, word.length())
                    .map(i -> valueUniqueToReplace.contains(i) ? '_' : word.charAt(i))
                    .collect(StringBuilder::new, StringBuilder::appendCodePoint, StringBuilder::append)
                    .toString();
}

private static String wordToGuess4(String word,List<Integer> valueUniqueToReplace){
    return valueUniqueToReplace.stream()
                               .reduce(new StringBuilder(word),
                                       (sb, i) -> sb.replace(i, i + 1, "_"),
                                       (a,b) -> a)
                               .toString();
}
```

Decide for yourself what is more readable, I for one would prefer the non stream approach

Comment: Thanks for your response, and if the focus of the problem was to replace certain characters in the string with dashes. My other question is, when is it advisable to apply stream?

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't need a stream. You can use [forEach](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)) like this.

```java
valueUniqueToRemplace.forEach(i -> wordToList.set(i, "_"));
```

If you want to use stream, you can do it like this

```java
valueUniqueToRemplace.stream.forEach(i -> wordToList.set(i, "_"));
```

Although these two approaches look similar, there are semantic difference.